# How to use similarities.Similarity in gensim?

Tags: python, gensim, cosine-similarity

How to use similarities.Similarity in gensim

Because if I use similarities.MatrixSimilarity:

`index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(tfidf[corpus])`

It just told me:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site- packages\gensim-0.12.4-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\gensim\similarities\docsim.pyc in __init__(self, corpus, num_best, dtype, num_features, chunksize, corpus_len)
513                 raise ValueError("cannot index a corpus with zero features (you must specify either `num_features` or a non-empty corpus in the constructor)")
514             logger.info("creating matrix with %i documents and %i features", corpus_len, num_features)
515             self.index = numpy.empty(shape=(corpus_len, num_features), dtype=dtype)
516             # iterate over corpus, populating the numpy index matrix with (normalized)
517             # document vectors
```

MyProgram:

It works okay when the input content is less than 20,000 lines, but when the lines go more than 20,000, it just cannot build an index for 'corpus_tfidf'.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import logging,time
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

    start=time.clock()

    def mmin(a,b):
        if a>b:
            return b
        else:
            return a
    from gensim import corpora, models, similarities

    fsource_01='E:\\cm_test\\ptfidf_test\\dim_items_terms_pre_pre.csv'
    fsource_02=fsource_01

    fcontent='E:\\cm_test\\ptfidf_test\\'

    f0=open(fsource_01)
    lines=f0.readlines()
    terms_list=[]
    for line in lines:
        line=line.strip('\n') #
        terms_sline=line.split(',') # es:['48909,53517,116593,55095']->['48909','53517','116593','55095']
        terms_list.append(terms_sline) 
    f0.close()

    from collections import defaultdict
    frequency = defaultdict(int)
    for text in terms_list:
            cnt_single=defaultdict(int)
            for token in text:
                frequency[token] += 1

    terms_list = [[token for token in text if frequency[token] > 1] for text in terms_list]

    terms_list_qc=[]
    for ttext in terms_list:
        cnt_single=defaultdict(int)
        terms_list_qc_item=[]
        for token in ttext:
            cnt_single[token]+=1
            if(cnt_single[token]<=1):
                terms_list_qc_item.append(str(token))
        terms_list_qc.append(terms_list_qc_item)

    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(terms_list)
    #dictionary.save(fcontent+'dim_items_terms.dict')

    corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in terms_list]
    #corpora.MmCorpus.serialize(fcontent+'dim_items_terms.mm', corpus)  
    end1=time.clock()   
    print "01.  Time Cost for trim_items_terms_to_sparse_matrix: %f s" % (end1-start)

    tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)
    corpus_tfidf = tfidf[corpus]
    end2=time.clock()   
    print "2.   Time Cost for bagofwords_to_tfidf: %f s" % (end2-end1)

    index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(tfidf[corpus_tfidf])
    #index.save(fcontent+'dim_items_terms_tfidf.index')
    f0=open(fsource_02)
    lines=f0.readlines()
    f1=open(fcontent+'out_recordid_tfidf.txt',"w")
    f2=open(fcontent+'out_cosine_tfidf.txt',"w")
    for line in lines:
        line=line.strip('\n') 
        doc = line
        vec_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(doc.split(','))
        vec_lsi = tfidf[vec_bow]
        sims = index[vec_lsi]

        sims = sorted(enumerate(sims), key=lambda item: -item[1])
        osize=mmin(len(sims),400)
        for i in range(osize):
            f1.write(str(sims[i][0]+1)+',')
            f2.write(str("%.2f"%sims[i][1])+',')
        f1.write('\n')
        f2.write('\n')
    f0.close()
    f1.close()
    f2.close()

    end3=time.clock()   
    print "3.   Time Cost for get_sim_itemsid_top_fh: %f s" % (end3-end2)
```

Comment: Looking at the traceback, it seems you need to supply more arguments in the constructor and/or make sure that `tfidf[corpus]` actually contains the data you think it does (maybe post`tfidf[corpus]` or parts of it here?).   I think Python sees it as a `"corpus with zero features"` which isn't a valid input unless you also supply `"num_features"`

Comment: @jDo I've figured out that the problem appeared cause I should use "corpus_tfidf = tfidf[corpus]" and then "index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(tfidf[corpus_tfidf])".It works okay when the input file contains less than 20,000,but when the input size increase to more than 20,000, "index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(tfidf[corpus_tfidf]])" showed a problem——"Memory Error".Can you help me with this?I've post the intire program in the question description.

Answer (score 4):

I replace the sentence

`index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(tfidf[corpus_tfidf])`

with

`index=similarities.Similarity('E:\\cm_test',tfidf[corpus_tfidf],len(dictionary))`

and it works fine.

Though it costs about 2079 s to get the results.

Comment: Could the similarities.Similarity(...) first argument be a Python list?